# Converting string to numeric in Stata

Tags: string, stata

I have survey data with the age of individuals in a variable named `agen`. Originally, the variable was string so I converted it to numeric using the `encode` command. When I tried to generate a new variable `hhage` referring to the age of head of household, the new variable generated was inconsistent.

The commands I used are the following:

```
encode agen, gen(age) 
gen hhage=age if relntohrp==1
```

The new variable generated is not consistent because when I browsed it: the age of the hh head in the first houshehold is 65 while the new number generated was 63. When I checked the second household, the variable `hhage` reported 28 instead of 33 as the head of the housheold head. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Run `help encode` and you can read:

> Do not use encode if varname contains numbers that merely happen to be stored 
>   as strings; instead, use `generate newvar = real(varname)` or `destring`; 
>   see real() or [D] destring.

For example:

```
clear all
set more off

input id str5 age
1 "32"
2 "14"
3 "65"
4 "54"
5 "98"
end

list

encode age, gen(age2)
destring age, gen(age3)

list, nolabel
```

Note the difference between using `encode` and `destring`. The former assigns numerical codes (1, 2, 3, ...) to the string values, while `destring` converts the string value to numeric. This you see stripping the value labels when you  `list`:

```
. list, nolabel

     +------------------------+
     | id   age   age3   age2 |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  1    32     32      2 |
  2. |  2    14     14      1 |
  3. |  3    65     65      4 |
  4. |  4    54     54      3 |
  5. |  5    98     98      5 |
     +------------------------+
```

A simple `list` or `browse` may confuse you because `encode` assigns the sequence of natural numbers but also assigns value labels equal to the original strings:

```
. list

     +------------------------+
     | id   age   age3   age2 |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  1    32     32     32 |
  2. |  2    14     14     14 |
  3. |  3    65     65     65 |
  4. |  4    54     54     54 |
  5. |  5    98     98     98 |
     +------------------------+
```

The `nolabel` option shows the "underlying" data.

You mention it is inconsistent, but for future questions posting exact input and results is more useful for those trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/str2num.htm) method? Sounds like you may have slipped up somewhere in your method.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer's answer is on-target, I would bet.